# How to iterate multiple elements in single loop using python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, for-loop, webdriver

Below code is working fine but i am using multiple loops.Is it possible to make it one loop to get all data.

> multiple loop code:

```
for post in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_1UoZlX"):
    mobile_link += [ post.get_attribute("href") ]

for post1 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_3wU53n"):
    mobile_name += [ post1.text ]

for post2 in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("._1vC4OE._2rQ-NK"):
    offer_price += [ post2.text ]
```

> Full Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import csv
chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Venkatesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
RegionIDArray = ["https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?otracker=categorytree&page=1&sid=tyy%2C4io", "https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?otracker=categorytree&page=2&sid=tyy%2C4io"]
mobile_link = []
mobile_name = []
offer_price = []
actual_price = []
data_list=[]
delay = 10 # seconds

for reg in RegionIDArray:
    try:
        driver.get(reg)
        WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]")))
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        print("Page is ready")

        for post in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_1UoZlX"):
            mobile_link += [ post.get_attribute("href") ]

        for post1 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_3wU53n"):
            mobile_name += [ post1.text ]

        for post2 in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("._1vC4OE._2rQ-NK"):
            offer_price += [ post2.text ]

        time.sleep(10)     
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Loading took too much time")
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's still multiple loops, but it's a bit neater with list comprehensions:

```
mobile_link += [ post.get_attribute("href") for post in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_1UoZlX") ]
mobile_name += [ post1.text for post1 in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_3wU53n") ]
offer_price += [ post2.text for post2 in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("._1vC4OE._2rQ-NK") ]
```

What was your reason for wanting a single loop? It seems like they are unrelated elements.

Comment: if you see these website https://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?otracker=categorytree&page=1&sid=tyy%2C4io&affid=businessp2 i want to get strike price value (text-decoration: line-through;) some time value will be there some time value will not be there. I am putting all information in array like mobile_link ,mobile_name, etc.. when i try to get the strike value is giving index out of range problem. here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253910/list-index-out-of-range-using-python-selenium?noredirect=1#comment73582762_43253910